# Default login in Raspberry is not working, how to go back to config screen?

Tags: security

I disabled the auto-login on our Raspberry and on `raspi-config` changed it to boot to console instead of booting straight to desktop, now its asking us to login first before booting up to the desktop (which is what we want) now the problem is the default login is not working:

```
pi
raspberry
```

I know I didn't change any passwords yet. Is there a way for us to boot back to the configure settings so we can change it to boot to desktop and then set the user password there?

Comment: we're still talking about raspbian, right?

Comment: yes we are still on raspbian

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry my previous answer caused this trouble, and I hope this will fix it!

You could try putting the SD-Card into a different computer and change the **cmdline.txt** to something like this: (Tutorial by [TNET Raspberry Pi pages](http://rpi.tnet.com/project/faqs/resetpasswd))

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 
console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait init=/bin/sh
```

(I added the `init=/bin/sh`). Then try to reboot, and hope that you get a shell.
Here, you need to mount the filesystem:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
passwd pi
(enter a new password)
sync
exec /sbin/init
```

Then, you should be able to log in again, using pi and your newly set password.
At the end, make sure to change the **cmdline.txt** back to the original. Good luck!

Comment: I don't see any cmdline.txt file

Comment: it should be on a seperate partition - sometimes calles 'boot' or similar.

Comment: We only see one partition called Recovery

Comment: I see recovery.cmdline, is that different?

Comment: are you looking at the sd card from a windows pc?
recovery.cmdline - I don't think that's what you're looking for, but you might as well try. (make a backup of your sd card prior to that, of course)

Comment: Yes from a windows pc

Comment: the file type of that recovery.cmdline is `CMDLINE File` i can't open it with a notepad. T_T

Comment: can you tell me a list of files/folders you have on that partition? you should be able to open it by opening a new file in notepad and then click file - open.

Comment: i opened it on notepad and this was the text inside the recovery.cmdline `quiet vt.cur_default=1 coherent_pool=6M elevator=deadline`

Comment: Files are 
`defaults (folder), os (folder), bootcode, BUILD-DATA, INSTRUCTIONS-README, recovery.cmdline, recovery.elf, recovery, recovery.rfs, RECOVERY_FILES_DO_NOT_EDIT, riscos-boot`

Comment: Can i just create it? the cmdline.txt?

Comment: it shouldn't hurt, give it a try. But I just looked again, the parition showing up on my windows machine is called "boot" and has the cmdline.txt file on it. also, "riscos-boot" sounds like risc os which which I have no experience, sorry.

Comment: am i going to crash the system if i create that cmdline.txt?

Comment: try opening another question asking for that, I have no idea why your filesystem looks completely different than mine.

Comment: I found this forum and its related to my problem. http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=64653&p=476555

Comment: Did i understand that right? That I need to get to recovery mode then open the file there?

Comment: Went to recovery and still did not see that cmdline.txt file. I wonder if I did anything wrong when we set it up.

Answer (score 2):

You obviously had NOOBS installed, which has 2 partitions.

DO NOT touch Recovery, which has all the distributions.

If you had installed Raspbian from NOOBS you should still have the /boot partition.

You could always try booting to NOOBS. I think by holding down the Shift while booting.

Answer (score 2):

For Raspbian:

If you are locked out and the password for user pi doesn't work, you should try to reboot to recovery by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and then holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while it will boot up.

Then you should see the recovery screen and on top there will be a button to edit config. Go there and switch to the tab to edit `cmdline.txt`.

Add `init=/bin/sh` to the end of the line, press OK and then press the GUI button Esc - that will just reboot with the edits you did

When it stops booting press enter - you should see a line with `#` sign.
That's when you input the commands to mount the file system and reset password:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
passwd pi
(enter a new password)
sync
exec /sbin/init
```

After you logged in with the new password and if you're not comfortable with VIM, you can repeat the reboot sequence, go back to the GUI and remove the `init=/bin/sh` from cmdline.txt

Otherwise do:

```
sudo vi /boot/cmdline.txt
```

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on the QEMU emulator.  Where:

```
pi::raspberry
```

did not work as the username::password combination.
I typed

```
root
```

for the username and it took me right in.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me.  What I found, posted on another forum was this:

> Hi, I'm a newbie who had the same problem. It was caused by running
>   xstart from terminal as root. This changed the ownership of file
>   /home/pi/.Xauthority to root which killed the auto login with
>   identical symptoms to the other posts on this topic. I changed
>   ownership back to pi with command "chown pi:pi /home/pi/.Xauthority"
>   (while logged in as root) and everything worked ok after that. Hope
>   that saves someone else the hours I spent trying to figure out the
>   problem! Cheers, Greg.

by gregmackers » Sat Aug 27, 2016 4:04 pm

`chown pi:pi /home/pi/.Xauthority` resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Check your keyboard settings!**

On default, it is set to en-us. In my case, the Z and Y are switched (german keyboard). And the result is: **raspberrz**

Comment: The default is not set to en-us, the default is set to en-gb which differs from en-us, mostly my special characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't get into the Pi, and don't mind factory resetting your Pi and reinstalling Raspbian, then hold the **Shift** key during boot (at the Raspberry with a gray background)

[image: Raspberry Pi recovery screen entry]

Then you'll be back to a screen just like the NOOBS Installer. Just reselect Raspbian and finish the reinstallation. Everything should be back to defaults and you should be back at the Raspbian Desktop.

Answer (score -1):

try typing the following

sudo passwd

(will ask for new password)

enter new password, and again to confirm

when installing files, make sure you choose username as root, then type in your newly entered password

Comment: u need to have. already logged in to do this. his problem is that he can't login