# can't login after modifying .bash_aliases

Tags: login

system: Raspbian lite 10

I made the `.bash_aliases` with some aliases. I accidentally put

```bsh
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

into `.bash_aliases` instead of `.bashrc`. After sourcing it I'm unable to login anymore. Is there an emergency mode to fix the files? (I have not set a root password, and I don't have an external sd-reader atm)

Comment: Hello. Without any "normal" logins or root or access to the SD card from another machine it's going to be tricky. Have you tried `ssh` or a serial terminal?

Comment: raspian (lite) just command line. i can just login as pi with standard pw. but the login prompt reappears since the files are not loaded properly

Comment: ssh is not enabled

Comment: Hello and welcome – Hold the Shift key during boot. Then you'll be back to a screen just like the NOOBS Installer. Just reselect Raspbian and finish the reinstallation. Everything should be back to default.

Comment: Also, check [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40475/44221) out.

Comment: If you don't have an external sd-reader, how do you flashed the Raspbian Lite image to the SD-Card?